# How can i limit the output of select statement for a varchar column in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

i have a table in which i store the information (product id and description ) of all my products, description column is of type VarChar2(200). i want to format the output of this column in select statement to only result me specific part of output string. E.G Here is my simple select statement:

```
Select PRODUCTId, PRODUCT_DESC From ProductTable Order By PRODUCTId Desc;
```

this statement result me the output as:

```
ProductId            Product_Desc
1                    Oxford English-Oxford-Oxford Press-Textbook
```

now i want only the specific part of the output result from product_description column. i have already checked Trim() function but that did not helped me. can someone help me?

Comment: Which "specific part" are you looking for? Do you want to split on spaces and take a certain piece?

Comment: Are you saying you have four (always four?) hyphen-delimited elements and you want to split them up; and extract one particular piece? Can you edit your question to explain what you need in more detail, with more sample values and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

A substring function may help.

`SELECT SUBSTR('ABCDEFG',3,4) "Substring"
     FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTR()` function. You can provide start and end position for the `product_desc` column.

The query should be like:

```
Select product_id,substr(product_desc,2,4) from producttable;
```

Here you'll get 4 chars from the second one.

Comment: but what if i want to trim string upto specific position based on some character in the string eg. trim upto where character is equal to '-' this symbol?

Comment: yes, you can use substr(trim(product_desc,'-'),startingposition,endingposition)

Comment: @user3743778 - that isn't valid syntax for trim; you'd need `trim('-' from PRODUCT_DESC)`. But it would only do anything if the string started or ended with a hyphen, it wouldn't remove everything up to the first hyphen in the example, say, You'd need something with `instr`, or a regular expression. It isn't clear what the OP really needs though.